# Uniform random distribution "base class" for both int and double?

Tags: c++, random, function-pointers, distribution, functor

I'm trying to make a function that will fill a list with random numbers, and based on the type of the list items it should generate either integer or floating point numbers. So far I've come up with the following code, and it works:

```
template <typename T>
void generateRandom(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());

    if( typeid(T) == typeid(int) ){
        uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(1000, 2000);
        auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
        generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
    }
    else if( typeid(T) == typeid(double) ){
        uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution(1000.0, 2000.0);
        auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
        generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }

}
```

However, I'm not really satisfied with this solution. It just feels like there should be some way to break out everything but the actual distribution from that IF statement. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
void generateRandom(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());

    X distribution;
    if( typeid(T) == typeid(int) )
        distribution = uniform_int_distribution<T>(1000, 2000);
    else if( typeid(T) == typeid(double) )
        distribution = uniform_real_distribution<T>(1000.0, 2000.0);
    else
        return;

    auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
    generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
}
```

(X is a placeholder for what's missing here)

But since `uniform_int_distribution` and `uniform_real_distribution` don't have a common base class, how would that be possible? I have tried playing around with function pointers and functors, but I never seem to get past that IF-statement, and it's annoying. Can this be solved in a more elegant way?

NOTE: It's part of a school assignment, and we have to use `generate()` and the `<random>` functions and templates to generate the random numbers. I think my original solution is acceptable, I just don't like the look of those duplicate lines of code in the IF-statement... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a typetrait-like class:

```
template<class T>
struct Distribution {};

template<>
struct Distribution<int> {
    typedef uniform_int_distribution<int> type;
};

template<>
struct Distribution<double> {
    typedef uniform_real_distribution<double> type;
};

template <typename T>
void generateRandom(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());

    typename Distribution<T>::type distribution = typename Distribution<T>::type(1000, 2000);
    ...
```

---

Another option is to create a template helper function that will accept the needed distribution as argument:

```
template<class T, template<class> class Distr>
void generateRandomHelper(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());

    Distr<T> distribution = Distr<T>(1000, 2000);

    auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
    generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
}

template<class T>
void generateRandom2(list<T>& numberList);

template<>
void generateRandom2<int>(list<int>& numberList) {
    generateRandomHelper<int, uniform_int_distribution>(numberList);
}

template<>
void generateRandom2<double>(list<double>& numberList) {
    generateRandomHelper<double, uniform_real_distribution>(numberList);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
template <typename T>
using my_distribution = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral<T>::value,
                   std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
                   std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
                                      std::uniform_real_distribution<T>,
                                      void>
                   >;
```

And then

```
template <typename T>
void generateRandom(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());
    my_distribution<T> distribution(1000, 2000);
    auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
    generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `std::is_integral` and `std::is_floating_point` instead of `std::is_same`.  More general and easier to understand, IMHO.

Comment: I'm not getting this to compile. For starters, `conditional_t` is not recognized. When I change it to `conditional`, that part is OK. But then the line where the distribution variable is declared gets a _"No matching constructor for initialization of 'my_distribution<int>'"_ error. Not sure how to solve that?

Comment: `std::contitional_t<Cond, T1, T2>` (C++14) should be replaced by `typename std::contitional<Cond, T1, T2>::type` (C++11) (or you can make your own alias).

Comment: Alright, that's got it working, thanks! Got more answers than I had hoped for, but I like this one the best. I guess it was something like this I had in mind, just didn't know there was such a thing as `conditional<>`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to calculate a type. That calls for (very, very, very) simple template meta programming:

```
template<typename T> class Distribution;
template<> class Distribution<int> {
    using distribution = uniform_int_distribution<int>;
};
template<> class Distribution<double> {
    using distribution = uniform_real_distribution<int>;
};


template <typename T>
void generateRandom(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());

    Distribution<T>::distribution distribution(1000, 2000);

    auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
    generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
}
```

This code does not compile, when T is neither `int` nor `double`. The compiler will complain, that there is no type `Distribution<T>::distribution` for your `T`.

Assuming, silently doing nothing e.g. for float, or unsigned int, is really what you need:

```
template<typename T> class Distribution {
public:
    // just anything, so that there is a type
    // not sure if this is really necessary
    using distribution = uniform_int_distribution<int>; 
    static const bool valid = false;
};
template<> class Distribution<int> {
public:
    using distribution = uniform_int_distribution<int>;
    static const bool valid = true;
};
template<> class Distribution<double> {
public:
    using distribution = uniform_real_distribution<double>;
    static const bool valid = true;
};


template <typename T>
void generateRandom(list<T>& numberList){
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(random_device{}());

    if(!Distribution<T>::valid) return;

    Distribution<T>::distribution distribution(1000, 2000);
    auto myGenerator = bind(distribution, randomGenerator);
    generate(numberList.begin(), numberList.end(), myGenerator);
}
```

Now the default just silently does nothing. To actually generate random numbers other than int or double, you have to specialize the template for your type, like I did for int and double.

Comment: Don't you need to write `typename` in front of `Distribution<T>::distribution distribution;`?

Comment: Did you try your proposed solution?

Comment: @5gon12eder no. I hope, that BadCash gets the concept of my solution, and not just tries and copy-paste from others. This is not a source for cheep code monkeys, but a place for learning.

Comment: @cdonat This is no excuse for advertising broken code.  You need not show a full working solution if you want to leave something for the asker to chew on but if you *do* post code, it should be correct.  Yours has numerous errors.  In addition to those already mentioned by nwp and Jarod42, the members of your trait `class` are all `private`.  And while ignoring unknown types might not be the best idea in the first place, you'll find that it also doesn't work like this because even if you `return` early, the whole body of your function must be correctly typed.  You'd need another SFINAE layer.