# Proper way to specialise a method within a templated class

Tags: c++11, templates, template-specialization

## Context:

I am currently trying to implement a `std::vector` like class. This is a school project: we **need** to write it like that, i.e. raw pointers and no STL-structure as `std::vector` or `std::valarray`.

As I want this class to be as generic as possible, this is a templated class. Here an extract of my Tvector.h file:

```
template <typename T>
class Tvector {
public:
    Tvector();
    // Other constructors and methods
    void fill_randomly();
private:
    T * _data;
    std::size_t _data_size;
    std::size_t _allocated_size;
};
```

The idea of the template is that my vector can store data of type `float`, `double`, `int`, `std::size_t`, `std::complex<double>` (the ones I need for the moment) and maybe even more if this is possible.

## Problem:

And I am currently facing a problem with the implementation of the method `void Tvector<T>::fill_randomly()` which, like its name says it, should fill my vector with random data.

## What I have tried:

### First try:

```
template <typename T>
void Tvector<T>::fill_randomly() {
    std::random_device rand_device;

    if( std::is_integral<T>::value ) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution_int;
        // Then fill the vector
        for(std::size_t i{0}; i < this->_data_size; ++i)
            this->_data[i] = distribution(rand_device);

    } else if( std::is_floating_point<T>::value ) {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution_real;
        // Then fill the vector
        for(std::size_t i{0}; i < this->_data_size; ++i)
            this->_data[i] = distribution(rand_device);

    } else if( /* is complex type */ ) {
        // More code looking like the 2 previous if-blocks

    } else {
        // Non-supported type
        static_assert( true, "The given type for Tvector is not supported by fill_randomly." );
    }
}
```

Of course I tried to create a `Tvector<double>` and call `fill_randomly` on it: compilation error on the declaration of `distribution_int`.

I was assuming that my if-structure with compile-time conditions will behave as pre-processor directives and that if the compile-time condition returns false, the entire corresponding block will be erased of my function definition. But seeing this compiler error, I think that my first assumption was false.

### Second try:

After some research, I saw that I can specialise my template methods like:

```
template <>
void Tvector<int>::fill_randomly() {
    std::random_device rand_device;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;
    // Then fill the vector
    for(std::size_t i{0}; i < this->_data_size; ++i)
        this->_data[i] = distribution(rand_device);
}
```

OK, fine, let's do this for the types I need then. But after nearly 10 copy-paste I said to myself "all theses copy-pastes... isn't it exactly why template are here? To avoid copy-pasting and make generic code?".

Then I searched more on forums and search engines in order to find a similar problem (and a "good" solution!). I can't find it.

## What I want:

If this is possible, I want an implementation of my `fill_randomly` method that do exactly the same thing as my first try and that can be easily extended and modified.

Of course I don't ask the implementation itself but the correct way to do it.

## Final question:

Is there a "good" way to do what I want? Something nicer than 10 or 20 method specialisations (and copy-pastes)?

PS: This is my first post in this forum. I tried to respect all the rules, I am not sure of the result. If there is any problem (missing information, not usual formatting, ...), please tell me.

Comment: You could always try doing something fancy with ````std::enable_if```` using the ````is_integral```` and ````is_floating_point```` checks.

Comment: This question seems very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907254/uniform-random-distribution-base-class-for-both-int-and-double

Comment: @mascoj `std::enable_if`'s documentation is a little complex, I will read it tomorrow and if I have questions I will come back. Thanks :)

Comment: @clcto The second answer is approximately what I was searching for. The only possible drawback is that I don't see for the moment how to tune my method for `std::complex`. I will try to write the code, and see if it goes well or not :)

Comment: @mascoj Finally the `std::enable_if` solution is not applicable here. Explained in the "Notes" section: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: @Nelimee Haven't tried it but you may be able to do a private function like ````template <typename T> void fill_randomly_impl( std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type input_type )```` then have your ````fill_randomly```` function call with a default constructed ````T````. No clue if that will work though, I don't have the personal time to try it, sorry.

Comment: @mascoj Thanks! That solution (seems to) work and is nicer! I will make more tests during the following week to ensure that the solution really worked, and then if everything seems fine I will edit my "solution" post and mark as solved. :)

Tanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT: post was edited and a solution was found. See comments in italics and the "Solution" part.*

## Synthesis of what I tried:

### First solution: `std::enable_if`

***Note**: See the final solution. The final solution uses `std::enable_if`.*

The solution can't work because of the mechanism of templates and because my template argument is not in the `fill_randomly` signature.

For a basic example and a short (but more complete) explanation of the problem see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), in the "Notes" section.

### Second solution: `std::conditional`

This solution was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32907541). In my specific case, it should work properly. But this is kind of ugly (personal point of view), especially if you have long conditions. In my case, if I used that solution, my `fill_randomly` code would look like that:

```
template <typename T>
void Tvector<T>::fill_randomly() {
    std::random_device rand_device;
    
    using my_distribution = std::conditional<std::is_integral<T>::value,
                                             std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
                                             std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value
                                                              || std::is_same< T, std::complex<float> >::value
                                                              || std::is_same< T, std::complex<double> >::value 
                                                              || std::is_same< T, std::complex<long double> >::value,
                                                              std::uniform_real_distribution<T>,
                                                              void>
                                             >;

    my_distribution distribution;
    // Then fill the vector
    for(std::size_t i{0}; i < this->_data_size; ++i) {
        if( std::is_floating_point<T>::value ) {
            this->_data[i] = distribution(rand_device);
        } else {
            this->_data[i] = std::complex<typename T::value_type>( distribution(rand_device),
                                                                   distribution(rand_device) );
        }
    }
}
```

Which:

1. Do not compile for the same reason as my "first try" function (and other reasons that are not obvious to me): the compiler tries to compile the line specialised for `std::complex` with a float type.
2. Is quite ugly and not easy to read.

I do not looked at casts (from double to complex for example), but I think this is not the best way to take.

### Third solution: template specialisation

***Note**: Text is as it was in the original post. This "solution" wasn't the best one, and the best solution I found is explained after.*

Finally, as @R sahu proposed, the only "good" solution I (and also my C++ professor) found for the moment is to specialise for each types I need, with copy-pastes.

So my final implementation will look like that:

```
template <>
void Tvector<double>::fill_randomly() {
    std::random_device rand_device;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;
    // Then fill the vector
    for(std::size_t i{0}; i < this->_data_size; ++i)
        this->_data[i] = distribution(rand_device);
}

template <>
void Tvector<std::complex<double>>::fill_randomly() {
    std::random_device rand_device;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;
    // Then fill the vector
    for(std::size_t i{0}; i < this->_data_size; ++i)
        this->_data[i] = std::complex<double>( distribution(rand_device),
                                               distribution(rand_device) );
}
```

And I will update my overloads whenever I need a type that is not implemented yet.

This is ugly, but this is the only solution I found.

## Solution:

Thanks to the comment of @mascoj in my first post, here is the solution I was searching for. This solution was tested successfully.

Finally my `Tvector` class look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Tvector {
public:
    Tvector();
    // Other constructors and methods

    // Should be in .cpp, is here for simplicity of the post.
    void fill_randomly() {
        // Call to the ONLY implemented function fill_randomly_impl().
        this->fill_randomly_impl();
    }
    
private:
    
    template <typename Integer = T>
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<Integer>::value, Integer >::type fill_randomly_impl() {
        // Implementation of the radom filling for integers.
        return Integer();
    }

    template <typename Real = T>
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<Real>::value, Real >::type fill_randomly_impl() {
        // Implementation of the radom filling for real numbers.        
        return Real();
    }

    // Other definitions of fill_randomly_impl for other types like complex types.
    
    T * _data;
    std::size_t _data_size;
    std::size_t _allocated_size;
};
```

First of all, the `fill_randomly_impl` function exists just because the signature and the return type of the `fill_randomly` function is fixed. If theses where not fixed, I could totally apply the same technique directly on my `fill_randomly` function, without introducing a `fill_randomly_impl` function.

#### Why the `template` definition before the method implementation?

Without the line `template <typename Integer = T>` the compiler sees the different definitions as overloads and say that the function cannot be overloaded.

Finally, this solution worked fine for me, thanks again to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a set of overloads to fill the data corresponding to different types. It simplifies the implementation of `Tvector::fill_randomly()`.

```
// Non-member functions to fill random values in the data array.

template <template <class> typename Distribution, typename T> 
void fill_random_values(T* data, size_t size)
{
   std::random_device rand_device;
   Distribution<T> distribution;
   for(std::size_t i{0}; i < size; ++i)
      data[i] = distribution(rand_device);
}

void fill_random_values(int* data, size_t size)
{
   fill_random_values<std::uniform_int_distribution>(data, size);
}

void fill_random_values(long* data, size_t size)
{
   fill_random_values<std::uniform_int_distribution>(data, size);
}

void fill_random_values(float* data, size_t size)
{
   fill_random_values<std::uniform_real_distribution>(data, size);
}

void fill_random_values(double* data, size_t size)
{
   fill_random_values<std::uniform_real_distribution>(data, size);
}

// Add other overloads of fill_random_values as necessary.

template <typename T>
void Tvector<T>::fill_randomly()
{
   fill_random_values(_data, _data_size);
}
```

Comment: Also, `static_assert(false, "Not supported.");` will prevent compilation even if the function is never instantiated.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but with this method I need to implement (and so copy-paste) by myself all the `fill_random_values` functions for each types I want no? Like `int`, `double`, `float`, `long double`, `std::complex<double>`, `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<long double>` and so on?

Comment: @aschepler, cleaned those up.

Comment: @Nelimee, yes. I hope someone can present a better answer.